# Exception in thread Main: Illegal format precision unresolved

Tags: java

So I've been trying to make this work and in similar error messages it was %f or %d where the wrong one was used for a double or integer. I tried switching them out but I keep getting these error messages.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 1
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Formatter.java:3138)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2874)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2713)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2655)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1053)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:949)
        at Backlog.displayRooms(Backlog.java:45)
        at HotelProject.main(HotelProject.java:36)
```

I was able to narrow down where in the code the issue is (It's over 300 lines so not feasible to upload it here) and I was hoping someone had an idea of what was going wrong on it.

```
import java.util.Random;

class Backlog
{
private int room[][][] = new int [5][6][3];

public Backlog() // Default Constructor
    {
        Random i = new Random();
        for (int u=0; u<3; ++u) // up
            for (int d=0; d<5; ++d) //down
                for (int a=0; a<6; ++a) //across
                {
                    room[d][a][u] = i.nextInt(10) +1;
                    if (room [d][a][u]< 4)
                    {
                        room[d][a][u] = 1; // Occupied
                    }
                    else if (room[d][a][u] >= 4)
                    {
                       room[d][a][u] = 0; // Empty
                    }
                }
    }
    public void displayRooms()
    {
        Random i = new Random();
        for (int d=0; d<5; ++d) // down
        {
            for (int u=0; u<3; ++u) //up
            {    for (int a=0; a<6; ++a) //across
                {
                    room[d][a][u] = i.nextInt(10) +1;
                    if (room [d][a][u]< 4)
                    {
                    room[d][a][u] = 1; // Occupied
                    }
                    else if (room[d][a][u] >= 4)
                    {
                    room[d][a][u] = 0; // Empty
                    }
                    System.out.printf("R# %d%d%d: ", a+1,u,d+1);
                    System.out.printf("%.1d ", room[d][a][u]); // Print across, up, then down 
                }
                System.out.println(" | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I made some edits but essentially you're code is attempting to print out %.1d on an integer value. This does not work.

```
import java.util.Random;

class Backlog {

    public static final int OCCUPIED = 1;
    public static final int VACANT = 0;
    private int room[][][] = new int[5][6][3];

    public Backlog() // Default Constructor
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int u = 0; u < 3; ++u) // up 0-2
            for (int d = 0; d < 5; ++d) //down 0-4
                for (int a = 0; a < 6; ++a) //across 0-5
                {
                    room[d][a][u] = random.nextInt(10) + 1; // 1-10
                    if (room[d][a][u] < 4) {
                        room[d][a][u] = OCCUPIED; // Occupied
                    } else if (room[d][a][u] >= 4) {
                        room[d][a][u] = VACANT; // Empty
                    }
                }
    }

    public void displayRooms() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int d = 0; d < 5; ++d) { // down 0-4
            for (int u = 0; u < 3; ++u) { //up 0-2
                for (int a = 0; a < 6; ++a) //across 0-5
                {
                    room[d][a][u] = random.nextInt(10) + 1; // 1-10
                    if (room[d][a][u] < 4) {
                        room[d][a][u] = OCCUPIED; // Occupied
                    } else if (room[d][a][u] >= 4) {
                        room[d][a][u] = VACANT; // Empty
                    }
                    System.out.println("down: " + d + ", up: " + u + ", across: "+ a);
                    System.out.printf("R# %d%d%d: ", a + 1, u, d + 1);
                    System.out.printf("%d ", room[d][a][u]);
                }
                System.out.println(" | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Backlog backlog = new Backlog();
        backlog.displayRooms();
    }
}
```

Output looks as follows:

```
R# 101: 0 R# 201: 1 R# 301: 0 R# 401: 0 R# 501: 1 R# 601: 0  | 
R# 111: 1 R# 211: 1 R# 311: 0 R# 411: 0 R# 511: 1 R# 611: 1  | 
R# 121: 0 R# 221: 0 R# 321: 0 R# 421: 0 R# 521: 0 R# 621: 0  | 

R# 102: 0 R# 202: 1 R# 302: 0 R# 402: 1 R# 502: 1 R# 602: 0  | 
R# 112: 0 R# 212: 0 R# 312: 1 R# 412: 0 R# 512: 0 R# 612: 1  | 
R# 122: 1 R# 222: 0 R# 322: 1 R# 422: 0 R# 522: 1 R# 622: 0  | 

R# 103: 1 R# 203: 1 R# 303: 0 R# 403: 0 R# 503: 0 R# 603: 1  | 
R# 113: 0 R# 213: 0 R# 313: 0 R# 413: 1 R# 513: 0 R# 613: 0  | 
R# 123: 0 R# 223: 1 R# 323: 1 R# 423: 1 R# 523: 1 R# 623: 1  | 

R# 104: 0 R# 204: 0 R# 304: 0 R# 404: 1 R# 504: 1 R# 604: 0  | 
R# 114: 0 R# 214: 1 R# 314: 0 R# 414: 1 R# 514: 0 R# 614: 0  | 
R# 124: 0 R# 224: 0 R# 324: 0 R# 424: 1 R# 524: 0 R# 624: 0  | 

R# 105: 0 R# 205: 0 R# 305: 0 R# 405: 0 R# 505: 0 R# 605: 0  | 
R# 115: 1 R# 215: 0 R# 315: 0 R# 415: 0 R# 515: 0 R# 615: 0  | 
R# 125: 0 R# 225: 0 R# 325: 0 R# 425: 0 R# 525: 0 R# 625: 1  |
```